# $\alpha^{2^{m} + 1}$ is a generator of $\operatorname{GF}(2^m)$?

Tags: s-boxes

This is from a paper ([Partitions in the S-Box of Streebog and
Kuznyechik](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/092.pdf)) about S-Boxes:

> Let $\operatorname{GF}(2^{2m}) = \mathbb{F}_2[X]/p(X)$ be a finite field of even degree defined by a primitive polynomial $p$. The multiplicative subgroup $\operatorname{GF}(2^{2m})^*$ is cyclic and generated by $\alpha$ which is such that $p(\alpha) = 0$.
>
> In this context, $\alpha^{2^{m} + 1}$ is a generator of the multiplicative subgroup of the subfield $\operatorname{GF}(2^m)$

I don't understand why it holds that $\alpha^{2^{m} + 1}$ is a generator of the subfield?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you haven't heard of splitting fields, here is an argument based on more elementary group theory.

Let $G$ denote a cyclic group. Then, it is easy to show (or you might already know it) that if $\alpha \in G$ is an element of order $n$ (we write $\mathsf{ord}(\alpha)=n$ to denote this), then 
$$\mathsf{ord}(\alpha^k)= \frac{\mathsf{ord}(\alpha)}{\gcd(\mathsf{ord}(\alpha),k)} = \frac{n}{\gcd(n,k)}.$$
Choose $G = \text{GF}(2^{2m})^*$ whose generator $\alpha$ is of order $n = 2^{2m}-1$, observe that $2^{2m}-1 = (2^m-1)(2^m+1)$, and deduce that
$$\mathsf{ord}(\alpha^{2^{m}+1}) = \frac{2^{2m}-1}{\gcd(2^{2m}-1,2^{m}+1)} = \frac{(2^m-1)(2^m+1)}{2^{m}+1}
= 2^m-1.$$
Thus, $\alpha^{2^{m}+1}$ generates the unique cyclic *subgroup* (of order $2^m-1$) of $\text{GF}(2^{2m})^*$ which itself is of order $2^{2m}-1$. Now, $\text{GF}(2^{m})$ is a subfield of $\text{GF}(2^{2m})$ and so this subgroup must be $\text{GF}(2^{m})^*$.

Comment: Beautiful explanation, thanks! Could you please also explain to me why $\operatorname{GF}(2^{2m}) \to \operatorname{GF}(2^{m}): \operatorname{Tr}_m(x) = x^{2^{m}} \oplus x$ holds?

Comment: I asked an extra question for that [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/71549/48800)

Comment: @winklerrr That is the *definition* of the relative trace from $GF(2^{2m})$ to $GF(2^m)$. No other explanation is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Remember that $\operatorname{GF}(p^m)$ is the splitting field of $x^{p^m} - x$ over $\operatorname{GF}(p)$.  If $m \mid n$ so that $\operatorname{GF}(p^n)$ is a field extension of $\operatorname{GF}(p^m)$, then for $u \in \operatorname{GF}(p^n)$, we have $u \in \operatorname{GF}(p^m)$ if and only if $u$ is a root of $x^{p^m} - x$.

Can you use these to show that $\alpha^{2^m + 1}$ is a unit in $\operatorname{GF}(p^k)$ and has maximal order $2^m - 1$?

Comment: Never heard of "splitting field" and I don't understand what $x^{p^m} - x$ means and what it has to do with the generator? Does it hold that $x^{p^m} = x$? So $x^{p^m} - x = 0$? But why over $\operatorname{GF}(p)$?
Could you please show me why $\alpha^{2m + 1}$ is a unit in $\operatorname{GF}(p^k)$?